# Angular2 reactive forms, how to pass FormGroup and FormArray to sub component

Tags: forms, angular

I want to build a dynamic form from a question-base, like in angular2 cookbook for dynamic forms. So I have a QuestionComponent:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">

  <ul *ngIf="question.multi" [formArrayName]="question.key">
    <li *ngFor="let control of form.get(question.key).controls; let lix=index">

      <div>

        <app-text-box [controlName]="lix"></app-text-box>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div *ngIf="!question.multi">
    <app-text-box [controlName]="question.key"></app-text-box>
  </div>
</div>
```

Based on `question.multi` there is a single FormControl or a FormArray. The Form-Input is in the TextBoxComponent:

```
<input class="form-control"
 [formControlName]="controlName"
 [id]="controlName" type="text">
```

But that does not work:

> Error in ./TextBoxComponent class TextBoxComponent - inline
>   template:0:28 caused by: formControlName must be used with a parent
>   formGroup

How do I get the information about the FormGroup into the component?

I tried it this way:
QuestionComponent:

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="col-md-10" >

  <ul *ngIf="question.multi" [formArrayName]="question.key" class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let control of form.get(question.key).controls; let lix=index">

      <div>

        <app-text-box [form]="form" [arrayName]="question.key" [controlName]="lix"></app-text-box>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div *ngIf="!question.multi">
    <app-text-box [form]="form" [controlName]="question.key"></app-text-box>
  </div>
</div>
```

TextBoxComponent:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div [formArrayName]="arrayName">
    <input  class="form-control" [formControlName]="controlName" [id]="controlName" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

But that yields an error when there is no FormArray.

Comment: Why not conditionally render the div with or without the formArrayName based on arrayName?

Comment: how do I do this without writing the input field twice?